# Tracking many dynamic forms with ng-model

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, forms

I'm generating dozens of forms on my page. Each form has several parameters (*not* the same for each form). I'm generating my forms as such (simplified):

```
<div ng-repeat='module in modules'>
    <form ng-submit='submitModule(module)'>
        <div ng-repeat='arg in module.args'>
            <input ng-model='models[module.name][arg.name]' id="{{ arg.name }}">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

You can see I'm trying to assign a unique `ng-model` to each input parameter by using a two dimensional array `models[module.name][arg.name]`.

Because I am planning on submitting this as JSON, the idea was that I could just do `models[some_module]` in my controller to get the full JSON, and then just post along.

Unfortunately this isn't working, when trying `models['test_module']` I get undefined, instead of my object. There are no errors elsewhere in the code, I've tested extensively. The problem comes from the use of multi-dimensional arrays here which is apparently a big no-no.

How should I handle my situation? IE: several forms, several inconsistent parameters, and a need to POST every param together as JSON.

EDIT: For info, my controller looks like:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('InputCtrl', function($scope, InputSvc) {
    $scope.models = {};

    InputSvc.list().success(function(modules) {
        $scope.modules = modules;
        $scope.models['test_module'] = {}
    });

    $scope.submitModule = function(module) {
        console.log($scope.models['test_module']);
    };

});
```

Comment: Don't think this is related to your error, but don't you need to test if `models[module.name]` exists first before accessing a property on it?  Something like `(models[module.name] = models[module.name] || {})[arg.name]`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could give each form a controller so the model is scoped to the form instance rather than the parent:

```
<div ng-repeat='module in modules'>
    <form ng-controller="FormCtrl" ng-submit='submitModule(module)'>
        <div ng-repeat='arg in module.args'>
            <input ng-model='formData[arg.name]' id="{{ arg.name }}">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then your `FormCtrl` would have the submit method and the model:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('FormCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.submitModule = function(module) {
        console.log($scope.formData);
    };
});
```

[Here is a Codepen](http://codepen.io/caroach1080/pen/mVwmmd)